# use SCOOP from inside a Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, deap, python-scoop

I'm learning deap and I want to use scoop.
Is it possible to test my programs in a notebook?

I learned from scoop documentation that
$ python -m scoop your_program.py is the right way to run. 
Is there any way I can pass '-m scoop' as argument to the notebook?

thanks.

Comment: Related (albeit unanswered): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50848644/is-it-possible-to-use-scoop-from-inside-a-jupyter-notebook

Comment: There have been serialization issues when you try to parallelize from within the notebook, see  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42051318/programming-deap-with-scoop and https://github.com/DEAP/deap/issues/57